# Why doesnt Ethereum support concurrency?

Tags: concurrency

Why doesnt Ethereum support concurrency?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)

Comment: because it would be an overkill. create concurrency at DApp level, and only use blockchain technology for storing money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an EIP draft written for it [here](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/648), but it wasn't implemented because the actual bottleneck for tx execution is state i/o, which would only be worsened by tx parallelizing.